# Get a point value with psycopg2 and PPyGIS

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, ppygis

I'm trying to setup a basic working postgis setup with python ppygis package.

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> import ppygis
>>> connection = psycopg2.connect(database='spre', user='postgres')
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE test (geometry GEOMETRY)')
>>> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES(%s)', (ppygis.Point(1.0, 2.0),))
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT * from test')
>>> point = cursor.fetchone()[0]
>>> print point
0101000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
>>>
```

I should have got a python object with separate X and Y coordinate. Something like

```
>>> Point(X: 1.0, Y: 2.0)
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm following http://www.fabianowski.eu/projects/ppygis/usage.html#installation

---

For posterity. I couldn't make it work, so to get point data this was what I did,

```
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) FROM test')
>>> point = cursor.fetchone()[0]
>>> print json.loads(point)['coordinates']
[1,2]
```

Comment: what does type(point) return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert your geometry column to WKT to get the point (or any geometry) as text format.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html

```
cursor.execute('SELECT ST_AsText(geometry) from test')
```

Probably something in ppygis is missing, because it seems like it converts the point geometry to the PostGIS ST_Geometry format but there is no function to convert it back (at least I didn't find any in the documentation).
If you use the normal `SELECT` statement it returns the geometry as PostGis ST_Geometry as well and does not convert it back. `cursor.fetchone()[0]` is a psycopg2 function and won't convert it back to the point format.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I emailed the developer and he says it *could* be a bug.

Comment: If you don't want to use the PPyGIS library, you can insert a point with the `ST_GeomFromText` method http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html

Comment: Can you comment on my edit? How good/bad is it? I really don't want to parse the string which get from `ST_AsText`

Comment: If you have only points you can use ST_X and ST_Y as well to get the XY values. http://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html `SELECT ST_X(geometry), ST_Y(geometry) FROM test;`